# EXCEL VBA - Multiple Sheets slow down VBA program - Optimize Memory

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, memory

I have and excel file with 7 sheets.
5 of them have a lot pre-filled formulas and one of them has a lot of text data (75000 rows).

And the 7th and final sheet has some data extracted from the 6th sheet (about 6-7 % of it).
For the 7th sheet I have created a VBA macro that will do some processing on the text.
If I delete the first 6 sheets, and leave only the last one, and run the Macro, the execution time is lighting fast.

The Problem is I would prefer to keep the first 6 sheets, and run the macro. But in this case, the execution time is extremely slow.

Is there any code or possibility to somehow unload the first 6 sheets from memory, so that the execution of the Macro will be fast?

I have tried the following options to optimize the memory and execution time, but nothing worked.

```
Public CalcState As Long
Public EventState As Boolean
Public PageBreakState As Boolean
Sub OptimizeCode_Begin()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

EventState = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False

CalcState = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

End Sub
```

Code I use on 7th Sheet:

```
Sub Itemsperlinestep1()

    'Optimize Code
    Call OptimizeCode_Begin

    Dim cell, ra3 As Range

    Set ra3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:XFD1")

    Do While True
        CountAA = Range("A2").Value

        For Each cell In ra3:
            If InStr(cell.Value, "<itemdata") Or InStr(cell.Value, "<figure") Then
            ElseIf cell.Value <> "" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -1) = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & " " & cell.Value
                Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(cell.Column).EntireColumn.Delete               
            End If

        Next cell

        Check = Range("A2").Value

        If CountAA = Check Then
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop


    'Optimize Code
    Call OptimizeCode_End
    Set ra3 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you show the code you use on the 7th sheet?

Comment: Added the code. Don't think it's very important though. 
My issue is: why it works lighting fast if I leave only 1 sheet, and why it works extremely slow if there are more sheets.

Comment: Should this line `Set ra3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:XFD1")
` be `Sheet7`?

Comment: No, Sheet1 is correct. The other sheets have different names. Sheet1 (the 7th sheet) is created by another Macro and then deleted after the processed text will be copied to the first 4 sheets for additional processing and analysis.

Comment: @Mihail-CosminMunteanu I don't follow you. Your code neither creates nor deletes a 7th sheet. What are you doing with the concatenated data before deleting the 7th sheet? If you are putting it in the other 6 sheets how does it work faster if you delete them? Regarding deleting columns (or rows), however, you should loop backwards.

Comment: @Brian, Another Macro creates Sheet1 (7th sheet), not the one I posted. Anyway we are wasting time discussing this. What you really need to understand is that the Macro I posted works LIGHTNING FAST, if I leave only one sheet. But it works EXTREMELY SLOW if I leave other sheets in the excel file.

Comment: @Brian, at the moment I have created different Macros for different parts of the process I want to perform on my Data, in order to find where it slows. 
And at the moment I noticed that the piece of code I added above is executed very slow. 
This part of the code is independent on the other sheets, because it's performed strictly on the data from Sheet1 (7th sheet). That's why I say it works very fast if I leave only that sheet in my excel file.

Comment: `cell` is `Variant`  in your code; `Range("A2").Value` try change to `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value`; you really need in `While` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everybody for your recommendations, but most of these solutions only improve the execution time by a couple of nanoseconds...

What I was talking about was a difference between a fraction of  second (When only 1 sheet is present) to a couple of hours when the first 6 sheets are left in the file.

So the obvious problem was the presence of those 6 sheets and the content in those 6 sheets and not the code I was running on the 7th Sheet.

So the only solution I found is to delete the pre-filled formulas and conditional formatting from first 5 sheets and use another Macro to copy them after I finish the processing on 7th sheet and paste the text.

This is not the best solution, but now it works fast.
I would definitely prefer a way of somehow freezing or unloading some sheets from memory... maybe this is something Microsoft could add in future releases.